# decltype to declare parameter of return type of a function (without auto)

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

This looks like a trivial question for me, maybe I didn't find the right documentation..

I have a struct A, and I want to define parameter b to be of return type of function A:

```
struct A{
    int operator[](int);
};
```

and then at some point

```
decltype(A::operator[]) b = 0;
```

I could do this: but it's ugly..

```
A a;
decltype(a[0]) b = 0;
```

(it can be double / int etc), I don't want to use templates.

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you want to use `decltype` without `auto`?

Comment: because I want to do something specific to the type, and I don't want to use the operator

Comment: Then the question is misleading, you are asking about the wrong thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand the need,  other than playing with the syntax. That is precisely what `auto` was designed for, and `auto` is supported by the same standard that added `decltype`...

At any rate, you need to simulate the function call:

```
decltype(std::declval<A>()[0]) b = 0;   // equivalent to `int b = 0;`
```

Comment: that doesn't compile.. need only utility no?

Comment: That is not a complete, self contained compilable piece of code, just the one line that you need. It does in fact require that you include `utility` for `std::declval` or if you don't want to, you can use other tricks: `decltype(*(static_cast<A*>(0))[0]) b = 0;`... but I would avoid this altogether. If you took the time to ask the real question you have, you might get better suggestions